# Where to start with coding and how to read files from .txt?

Tags: c#, class

I am studying something that is not programming, but I have this course which is based on c# and I have a problem.

- I need to create a Windows form app that needs to read data from txt. If loading was correct, the app needs to put msg that everything was loaded well, but if there's problem, I need to put an error message.
- Also, I need to define class, put all data from that txt in array. Files in that txt files are all numbers sorted line by line

I have a big problem here because I don't understand anything. I've done whole design thing, making buttons and stuff but I have problem with coding ofcourse.

Where should I put that class? If "Load" is menu strip, I need to double click it, and put class in that code? What class should look like? I'm sorry, I know these are basics, but this is so unimportant course for my degree and I need it to finish.

This is just beginning of this app, I think I could figure next steps but please help me with this...

Comment: StackOvverflow is unfortunately not a code writing service, you've got to try something first. If you run into problems with your code, come back to SO and ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

the question is too broad in my opinion but there are multiple ways to read files in c# and the following code is from microsoft docs. its for a console application but would work with winforms aswell. the key part here is System.IO.File.ReadAllText function.

```
class ReadFromFile {
static void Main()
{

    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");

    // Display the file contents to the console. Variable text is a string.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);

    // Example #2
    // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element
    // of the array is one line of the file.
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

    // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
    }

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

}